# Combine multiple signals for one model (using Html.Events and Keyboard signals)

Tags: elm

I am fairly new in Elm. I am currently discovering that language while experimenting it. Although the use of signals appears complex. Here below is a working example of my webpage, which handles multiple paragraphs (addition, removal, edition, ...) .

```elm
-- start
main: Signal Html.Html
main = Signal.map (view actions.address) model

view: (Signal.Address Action) -> Model -> Html
view address model = ... (displaying paragraphs with buttons, ect)
```

This snippet initiates the model. By mapping the actions to the model using `Signal.map`, i am able to handle click events from buttons (imported Html + Event module)

```elm
model: Signal Model
model = Signal.foldp update makeEmptyModel actions.signal
```

Here, i start with an empty model. The `update` function allows me to update the model after click events on buttons.

```elm
update: Action -> Model -> Model
update action model = ....
```

The `Action` is a type which handles multiple actions that i have defined like "AddParagraph", "RemoveParagraph" ...

This works so far. Now, when checking the packages, i found [`Keyboard`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Keyboard). That appears interesting, so I want to add a new functionality. If the user presses Alt+A, all paragraphs got selected. (Like Ctrl+A in file explorer)

But it appears that it's not easy to combine that with the current signal mapping that I have. I decided to dig into [`Signal`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Signal) and found [`Signal.merge`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Signal#merge). So i can use it right ? My attempt to merge the keyboard signal to my current signals is

```elm
main = Signal.merge
    (Signal.map (view actions.address) model)
    (Signal.map (view actions.address) keysDown)
```

(the keysDown is from `import Keyboard exposing (keysDown)` import)

But that doesn't work. I get the next error

```
The 2nd argument to function `map` is causing a mismatch.
160│      Signal.map (view actions.address) keysDown)
                                            ^^^^^^^^
Function `map` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
Signal { focused : Bool, selected : Bool, ... }

But it is:
    Signal (Set.Set Char.KeyCode)
```

It appears that when using `Signal.merge`, it expects multiple signals which handles the same output. Well that's what i *want*. But that doesn't work it seems.

**Question: How can i add Keyboard signal to the current design ?**

Or am I wrong with my expectations about `Signal.merge` ? That I'm using `Signal.merge` for wrong purpose ? Should I use [`Signal.map2`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Signal#map2) instead ? If so, how can I use it with my current example* ? Or is there a better approach ?

- *if the solution is map2, can you add an explanation ? That is because I don't understand that "map2" stuff*

Answer (score 3):

The Signals you send to `merge` must be of the same type. You'll need to add another function that maps the keyboard input to an `Action` prior to merging.

There are a couple ways to achieve this. Here's an example using the basic Counter examples and `Signal.merge`. Of importance is the use of the `keyPressesToAction` signal mapping function

```elm
import Signal
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Keyboard
import Char

type Action = NoOp | Increment | Decrement

actions : Signal.Mailbox Action
actions =
  Signal.mailbox NoOp

update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp -> model
    Increment -> model + 1
    Decrement -> model - 1

model =
  Signal.foldp update 0 (Signal.merge actions.signal keyPressesToAction)

keyPressesToAction =
  let
    keyCodeToAction keyCode =
      case Char.fromCode keyCode of
        '+' -> Increment
        '-' -> Decrement
        _ -> NoOp
  in
    Signal.map keyCodeToAction Keyboard.presses

main =
  Signal.map (view actions.address) model

view address model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick address Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , text <| toString model
    , button [ onClick address Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]
```

Another way to achieve the desired results is by using a `port` dedicated to converting key presses to `action` signals. This gets rid of the need to merge signals because it instead causes key presses to trigger the Mailbox you've already set up.

In this scenario, the `model` function goes back to the way it was, then we add the port below called `triggerActionOnKeyPress`, which uses the identical `keyPressesToAction` signal mapping function from above. Here are the relevant lines:

```elm
model =
  Signal.foldp update 0 actions.signal

port triggerActionOnKeyPress : Signal (Task.Task Effects.Never ())
port triggerActionOnKeyPress =
  Signal.map (Signal.send actions.address) keyPressesToAction
```

Comment: So, I have used `Signal.merge` incorrectly ... But, now i am unable to add paragraphs. I have a textarea where i can insert text. When i click on the button, it adds that text to the paragraphs that i've created. Even with your port solution, i even cannot enter text data to my textarea. That's because the `_ -> NoOp` of keyPressesToAction overrides it. How can i ensure that the signals is only sent if i press Alt ? Then i can use Alt+A simply

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing your code. It sounds like something else may be at fault. Handling the key press signal should not affect typing into textboxes.

Comment: I have c/p'ed your example ( the first code block) onto the [online editor](http://elm-lang.org/try) and there, using "+" and "-" key didn't work. Clicking on these buttons however works. Probably something is not right there :)

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue with [Keyboard.presses in Firefox](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/326) that should be resolved soon. The example works in Chrome just fine. Perhaps your code will work in Chrome too?